# Division formula adding together

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to do a simple formula in Excel, but getting an error. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Can anyone help please?

```
=SUM(C10:C12)/B2 + (N17:N24/5)
```

Comment: Please explain what you think the formula should do.

Comment: Do you mean to use SUM(N17:N24), because otherwise you are trying to return an array of N17/5, N18/5, N19/5, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parenthetical error:

```
=SUM(C10:C12)/B2 + SUM(N17:N24)/5
```